# Foreach statement for two OfType<>

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I write a foreach statement that includes both of these statement together

```
//clear textboxes
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            {
                c.Text = "";
            }
        }
        //clear price label text
        foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            if ((string)c.Tag == "Clearable")
            {
                c.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write it in 1 loop but you'll still need separation of logic for each type of Control:

```
foreach(Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
    if(c is TextBox)
    {
        var tb = c as TextBox;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
            tb.Text = "";
    }

    if(c is Label)
    {
        var l = c as Label;
        if(l.Tag != null && l.Tag.ToString() == "Clearable")
            l.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think using `is` and then `as` is bad code style. You essentially cast object twice. It is better to cast with `as` and then check for `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Working off of Abbas answer, to remove the if statement, you could have an overridden method to deal with each one.

```
private void ClearControl(Control control)
{
    ProcessControl((dynamic)control);
}

private void ProcessControl(TextBox textbox)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
        tb.Text = "";
}

private void ProcessControl(Label label)
{
    if(l.Tag != null && l.Tag.ToString() == "Clearable")
        l.Text = "";
}

private void ProcessControl(Control control)
{
    // Nothing to do
}

// Calling code
// if Controls is a list, than the ToList() does not need to be called.
panel1.Controls.ToList().ForEach(ClearControl);
```

Comment: I would probably use `dynamic` as little as possible, that is `private void ClearControl(Contol control)` and `ProcessControl((dynamic)control);`. That way, you don't have to check the type manually.

Comment: @svick I tried it that way.  The problem is by making it a control only the ProcessControl(Control control) method is called.  By making it a dynamic, a little bit of reflection is used to call the correct method.  I will take that little hit in performance in a windows app to save the if/ifelse/else statements that will pop-up.

Comment: I'm saying you should use `dynamic`, but use it later than you currently do. Notice the cast to `dynamic` in my prposed call to `ProcessControl()`.

Comment: Got it now.  I got the two methods mixed up.  I like your way, it gets rid of an extra if statement :)  I made the change

Comment: This answer is the bad practise i think. Creating a dummy method and using dynamic cast?

Comment: I my opinion, it is better than a method full of if/elses.

Comment: I agree with Peter, this looks ugly to me. `if` on the other hand is a basic operator, there is nothing wrong with using it. Method full of if-elses (would not call a method with two `if`-s that, but oh well) is no good either, but it can be easily split into sub-methods by simple refactoring.

Comment: You guys are completely breaking one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.  To add a new control, you have to modify the original class, this pattern will allow you to add logic for other controls without having to modify the original class (closed for modification, open for extension).  You can also now move this logic into their own classes, and make them into some kind of service.  And for me, this coding style makes way more sense, and is much easier to read than a whole bunch of if/elses or switches.

Comment: @Jeff Vanzella, again, if-else can be refacotred to support inheritance. The thing is however - there is a clear deep design issue with the application itself, if code such as this is needed, imho. Personally, i would not use your solution, nor will i use if-else's or w/e. Instead I would change the design of my UI, so that there is no `foreach` loops such as one in the original post to begin with :)

Answer (score 1):

The Control class it self has the Tag and Text properties no need additional separation.

```
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls.Where(c => c is TextBox || (c.Tag is string && (c.Tag as string) == "Clearable")))
{
    c.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: You would need to check if it's a label also, to have it do the same as the original code.

Comment: True if it's really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary of the types that you want to handle and the functions to determine if they should be cleared:

```
var clear = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Control, bool>>();
clear.Add(typeof TextBox, c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text));
clear.Add(typeof Label, c => (string)c.Tag == "Clearable");

// clear controls
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls) {
  Func<Control, bool> f;
  if (clear.TryGetValue(c.GetType(), out f) && f(c)) {
    c.Text = String.Empty;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not bad but it can be slow as hell becouse of the reflection.

Comment: @PeterKiss: What reflection?

Comment: c.GetType() is getting the type at runtime but ofcourse this overhead can be tagged with micro optimalization.

Comment: @PeterKiss: That's not reflection. Getting the type of an object is a rather simple operation. Calling `Int32.ToString` for example takes a lot longer, and that is not generally considered "slow as hell"...